# Product placements in I, Robot

Tags: product-placement, i-robot

Probably most of the viewers of the movie I, robot noticed the [Audi product placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audi_RSQ). Also converse are [pretty visible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5WgAubyhYw). But I wonder it the movie has more of such ads, maybe not that obvious as this. Is there some official list of them?

[image: Will Smith and Converse]
[image: Will Smith and Audi]

I think that this movie does product placement better than others. Cars are cool and shoes have a funny scene. It is not just some random ad on the background, it is part of the plot. That it why I am interested in this.

I would appreciate also some more info than just a name of the brand.

Comment: This sort of thing has no connection to the plot and is merely a list question. If you have a reason why you think this information is valuable, please edit your question to convey it. As is, this question is trivia. Please see this related meta question for more information. https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/are-we-here-to-identify-the-random-stuff-that-people-use-in-films-or-tv-shows

Comment: I think that this movie does product placement better than others. Cars are cool and shoes have a funny scene. It is not just some random ad on the background, it is part of the plot. . That it why I am interested, I will put this into the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until I can find an official list, [Brandspotters.com](http://www.brandspotters.com/movie.aspx?id=551) has compiled the following list:

- Audi
- Converse
- FedEx
- Ivory
- JVC
- Ovaltine Cafe
- Prudential

Comment: I know the question is closed, but if you could provide more info I would be glad. Are these placements somehow special? Or is it (to quote me): "some random ad on the background"?

Comment: Probably more likely that the production received money in exchange for promotion the various businesses. The writers then create an in-universe reason for these products to appear - the FedEx robot is a good example of blending advertising with the story. We're on the verge of drone delivery, so a robot delivery is believable.